# Multiply quantities for all parent child relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy

I have a table kind of this.

```
======================================
ID  |  Description|Quantity| Parentid|
=====================================
1   |  Main       | NULL  | NULL   |
2   |  Sub        |  20   |  1     | 
3   |  Sub2       |  21   |  1     | 
4   |      A1     |  32   |  2     | 
5   |      B1     |  51   |  3     | 
6   |      B2     |  43   |  3     | 
7   |      C1     |  34   |  4     |
9   |      D1     |  22   |  5     |
10  |      D2     |  90   |  5     |
11  |      E1     |  21   |  7     |
12  |      F1     |  2    |  11    |
13  |      F2     |  42   |  11    |
14  |      G1     |  12   |  13    |
-------------------------------------
```

I want total quantity of G1.. parent of G1 is F2. parent of F2 is E1 . parent of E1 is C1. parent of C1 is A1. parent of A1 is Sub. Parent of Sub is Main. so the total quantity of G1 is `(12*42*21*34*32*20=230307840)`.

How to get that answer with sql query?

Comment: Your table structure and data is not very clear - try including the SQL to build and populate it.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is another good option to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TotalQuantity AS
(
    SELECT  Quantity, ParentID
    FROM    MyTable
    WHERE Description = 'G1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TQ.Quantity * COALESCE(T.Quantity,1), T.ParentID
    FROM    TotalQuantity   TQ
    INNER JOIN MyTable      T   ON T.ID = TQ.ParentID
)

SELECT * FROM TotalQuantity
WHERE ParentID IS NULL
```

Comment: Your query gets the correct results, but I'm puzzled by your use of `parentid`.  Shouldnt that be `childid`?  A null parent indicates that they are the first record, not the last.

Comment: smarter solution for my problem.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will give the increasing totals for each generation.

```
WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, Description, Quantity, Generation, ParentId)
AS
(
   SELECT Id, Description, Quantity, 0 as Generation, ParentId
        FROM Table1 AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL        
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NextGeneration.Id, NextGeneration.Description,
          ISNULL(NextGeneration.Quantity, 1) * ISNULL(Parent.Quantity, 1), 
          Parent.Generation + 1, Parent.ChildId
   FROM Table1 AS NextGeneration
   INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.ParentId = Parent.ChildId    
)
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
```

For `G1` simply

```
select quantity from Hierarchy where description = 'G1' -- result = 230307840
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9f51/2)

Comment: sure. I will never forget :)

Comment: @Student hope you didnt forget me.